# ntfs partitions

Tags: linux, files, permissions, linux-mint, filesystems

**I use Linux Mint on a dual boot with Windows 10.**
**How to change ntfs partitions permission from read only to read/write.**

[image: when i click properties at partition, i see it.]

[image: When I click properties of some folders I can't cut or delete]

Answer (score 1):

#### Changing Permissions, In General

Your screenshot shows 'root' as the owner of the directory.  In order to change permissions, you must be logged in as 'root.'  This can be accomplished either via sudo or an actual login in a virtual terminal.

It is generally considered a poor practice to login as 'root' via a graphical Xwindows session.  So, for most privileged actions, such as changing directories from 'root' to 'user1', I use the:

```
$sudo -s
```

command which drops me into a general purpose 'root' shell rather than just running a single command as 'root.'

In any case, you will need to be logged in as 'root' and use one of two methods:

- Change the owner of the directory to your normal user login. (better)

  `# chown -R owner:group`

  The -R will change all subdirectories.  The 'owner' is your username.  And the 'group' is typically also your username.
- Change the permissions to allow global write permissions. (not as good)

  `# chmod -R 777 .`

  This will accomplish the same, but is very insecure.  It may also have an undesired effect of allowing non-executable files to be 'executed', leading to strange behavior when some files are 'double-clicked.'

#### Writing NTFS

I haven't used NTFS in a long time.  However, the last time I integrated my filesystem with NTFS, I needed to install the NTFS Fuse module.

On my go-to distro, Debian, the NTFS Fuse module is part of the ntfs-3g package:

```
#apt-cache show ntfs-3g
```

Truncated output:

```
Package: ntfs-3g
Version: 1:2016.2.22AR.2-2
Installed-Size: 1343
Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Pre-Depends: fuse
Description-en: read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
 NTFS-3G uses FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) to provide support for the NTFS filesystem used by Microsoft Windows.
Homepage: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/
```